# htmlParse() segfault error in R XML package: 'memory not mapped'

Tags: memory, r, segmentation-fault, html-parsing

I am using R 2.11.1 and XML package 3.1-0, and I was going through an example from [R2GoogleMaps](http://www.omegahat.org/R2GoogleMaps/) when I encountered a segfault error.

```
#library(RJSONIO)
library(R2GoogleMaps)
library(XML)
#library(RCurl)

load("b.rda") # find in the sampleDocs folder in source file of R2GoogleMaps

center = c(mean(range(b$lat)), mean(range(b$long)))
code = addOverlay(gpolyline(b))

d = googleMapsDoc(code, center, zoom = 11, dim = c(750, 700), file = "simplePolyline.html")
```

Below is an easily reproducible code that gets the same error:

```
> library(XML)
> a <- htmlParse("http://bm2.genes.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_current/library/XML/man/xmlTreeParse.html")
> a

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x55aa44, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .Call("RS_XML_dumpHTMLDoc", doc, as.integer(indent), as.character(encoding),     as.logical(indent), PACKAGE = "XML")
 2: saveXML(from)
 3: saveXML(from)
 4: asMethod(object)
 5: as(x, "character")
 6: cat(as(x, "character"), "\n")
 7: print.XMLInternalDocument(<pointer: 0x1016363f0>)
 8: print(<pointer: 0x1016363f0>)

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection: 1
aborting ...

Process R segmentation fault at Sat Jul 31 22:07:02 2010
```

The problem also seems to be doing a `saveXML()` on the `htmlParse()` file.

When I was writing up another code that used `htmlParse()`, I don't recall ever encountering this problem (although I don't remember if I called a `htmlParse()` object explicitly). So I'm not entirely sure if this is a recent problem or not. The only difference between then and now (that I can remember) is that I've installed many of the [OmegaHat packages](http://www.omegahat.org/) from source.

I was curious if anyone else was getting this error. To explore if the cause lies with my laptop, I have restarted and upgraded my OS as a basic step. What might be the problem? Thanks.

**edit**: just for ref:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.11.1 (2010-05-31) 
x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0 

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  grid      methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] XML_3.1-0     digest_0.4.2  reshape_0.8.3 plyr_0.1.9    proto_0.3-8  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] ggplot2_0.8.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that almost by definition a segmentation fault constitutes a bug.
Your example works for me (see below).

I would (a) make sure you have the latest version of XML and that the error
still occurs there; (b) contact the maintainer of the XML package (try

> maintainer("XML") 
>   ) and provide your example and the results of sessionInfo()

good luck.

=============

> library(XML)
>   a <- htmlParse("http://bm2.genes.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_current/library/XML/man/xmlTreeParse.html")
>
> sessionInfo()
>   R version 2.11.1 (2010-05-31) 
>   i486-pc-linux-gnu

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C              LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  grid      methods
[8] base

other attached packages:
[1] XML_3.1-0     reshape_0.8.3 plyr_1.0.3    proto_0.3-8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] ggplot2_0.8.8

Comment: Oops, I see that you did specify your version of XML (which seems to
be the latest)

Comment: Thank you Ben. Contacting the package creators is probably the best bet.